# Edittext in Listview with wrong input onresume

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, onresume

I have a a listview with each row having a text field and edittext field. I have them all fight on screen. When I resume the activity by either getting a call, going back etc the input in the edittext fields does not match up with what was originally enter into. I was wondering how I could setup onresume or a saved instant state to prevent that and insure that the correct input is in the correct edittext field.

This is the code I'm working with.

```
public class editview extends ListActivity {
    private dbadapter mydbhelper;
    private PopupWindow pw;
    public static int editCount;
    public static ListView listView;
    public ItemAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mydbhelper = new dbadapter(this);
        mydbhelper.open();


        View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.addFooterView(footer);
        showResults();
        }

    //Populate view
    private void showResults (){
        Cursor cursor = mydbhelper.getUserWord();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        String[] from = new String[] {dbadapter.KEY_USERWORD};
         int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textType};
         adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.edit_row, cursor,
                        from, to);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            this.setListAdapter(adapter);
            editCount = adapter.getCount();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


            //footer button
            public void onClick(View footer){
                    final MediaPlayer editClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button50);
                    editClickSound.start();
                    if (ItemAdapter.inputValues.containsValue("")){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all fields", 1000).show();
                          }else{
                          startActivity(new Intent("wanted.pro.madlibs.OUTPUT"));
                                };

                }
...

            }
            @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPause() {

                super.onPause();

            }


        }
//custom cursor adapter
class ItemAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Cursor cursor;
    static Map<Integer, String> inputValues = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    static String oldText;


    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from,
            int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);
        this.cursor = cursor;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }


    static class ViewHolder implements TextWatcher {
        protected TextView text;
        protected EditText edittext;
        protected int position;

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            Log.e(String.valueOf(position), "Position in array");
            inputValues.put(position, editable.toString());

        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_row, null);


             holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textType);
            holder.edittext = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            holder.edittext.addTextChangedListener(holder);
            holder.position = position;
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int label_index = cursor.getColumnIndex("userword"); 
        String label = cursor.getString(label_index);

        holder.text.setText(label);
        oldText =  inputValues.get(position);
        holder.edittext.setText(oldText == null ? "" : oldText);

        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Comment: EditText in ListView.. Yeah, I'd say forget about it. Seriously, it's buggy on android.

Comment: I've used a listview since the amount of edittext I need are dynamic. I need anywhere from 4-10 based on what the user selected in previous activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, EditTexts in ListViews are a big pain in the butt, just in case you start running into issues. Second, you don't seem to be saving the `inputValue` strings at any point. At least you should serialize the values in `onSaveInstanceState()` and read them back in `onCreate()`. You shouldn't be storing them in the adapter either. You should really have a proper "model" (an object with label and input values) backing the adapter. A SimpleCursorAdapter is not very well suited for modifying data in parallel.